# Save R JSON object with new lines for each record

Tags: json, r

I'm trying to save a JSON object where each line is a record.  How can I save the JSON object so that the number of lines is equal to the number of records (5 in example below)?

```
  library(jsonlite)
  df=mtcars[1:5,]
  x <- jsonlite::toJSON(df)
  # remove brackets
  x=substr(x,2,nchar(x)-1)
  write_lines(x,"tmp.json")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `jsonlite::stream_out`

```
df <- mtcars[1:5,]
jsonlite::stream_out(df, file('tmp.json'))
```

that gives newline delimited JSON or "ndjson"

Comment: This json output does not include [] to begin and end json or commas between elements. BAD result for me.

Comment: @pauljohn32 the output of `stream_out()` is not valid JSON, each line is valid JSON though

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick:

```
x2 = strsplit(x, '\\},\\{')
write.table(x2,"tmp.json")
```

Answer (score 1):

`jsonlite::stream_out` will only work for flat `data.frame` objects:

```
jsonlite::stream_out (list (iris, mtcars)) # error!
```

More complex structures can be written with intact line breaks simply using `writeLines`:

```
x <- jsonlite::toJSON (list (iris, mtcars), pretty = TRUE)
con <- file ("tmp.json")
writeLines (x, con)
close (con)
```

`jsonlite::fromJSON` will read this straight back.